# Emacs: Set tab indent for just one file on the fly

Tags: emacs

I work on an open source project where the creator sets his tab-indents to 2 spaces.

I'd like to just enable it on the fly for the one file I work on and not other files of the same type. There must be something like <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-tab-indent`. It is a JavaScript file ending in `.js`.

I know I can use:

```
(setq-default tab-width int)
```

inside my `.emacs` file, but I rather just call an <kbd>M-x</kbd> `command` to set it and forget it during my duration of working on this file. I tried <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos` and Google but couldn't find the specific command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a file ".dir-locals.el" in the project's directory and fill it like this:

```
((nil . ((tab-width . 2))))
```

This will take care of setting tab-width automatically and you don't have to modify the actual file (which is likely version-controlled.)

See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) for more information about the format. I believe this requires Emacs 23.

Answer (score 31):

You can make the variable `js-indent-level` local to the buffer using:

`M-x make-variable-buffer-local <RET> js-indent-level <RET>`

Then you can set that variable in the buffer using:

`M-x set-variable <RET> js-indent-level <RET> 2`

Comment: This should be the right answer... bonus points if there can be a function we can add to our .emacs that does these 2 steps in 1!

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi You can always customize js-indent-level (open a .js file, then M-x customize-variable <RET> js-indent-level <RET>). This will allow you to set a default and save it for future sessions. The question was about changing the indentation on the fly for a specific buffer.

Comment: What I mean is, it would be awesome to have a single function you can invoke with M-x that makes a variable buffer-local, and changes it's value to something.  So like `M-x set-variable-locally`

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to do this for a **single buffer** is to use `M-x set-variable`.

1. Type `M-x set-variable` and press enter
2. When prompted for the variable to set, set `tab-width` then press enter
3. You'll be prompted with the line `Set tab-width (buffer-local) to value:`. 
   Put the value you want, then hit enter

The buffer should instantly be updated with the new value.

Comment: This is the simplest and most straightforward answer without adding something to the project directory. Note that it may not be `tab-width` you're after - in fact, that shouldn't alter the file at all, just how it's displayed. You're more likely to need some sort of `-indent-offset`, dependent on your major mode. For instance, I was looking at an HTML file in web-mode (which I hardly ever do, so it wasn't configured properly). I needed to set `web-mode-markup-indent-offset`.

Answer (score 14):

You could also use file local variables to automate omrib's solution for that one file, by adding this to it:

```
// Local Variables:
// js-indent-level: 2
// indent-tabs-mode: nil
// End:
```

Comment: Variables set through the Local Variables section are automatically made buffer-local, so your `eval` was unnecessary, and I removed it.

Comment: Even better (and so obvious in retrospect). Thanks for that cjm.

Comment: Only thing about this is that I would have to make sure I don't commit this line in the public repo.

Comment: I've found a solution to that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240111/emacs-set-tab-indent-for-just-one-file-on-the-fly#6278744

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by others, one issue with the [File Local Variables approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240111/emacs-set-tab-indent-for-just-one-file-on-the-fly#6241013) is that you need to modify the file, and that's not ideal if you need to keep those declarations out of version control.

If you want the variables to apply to *all* files under a given directory, then Directory Local Variables is obviously the way to go, and you can implement that with either a `.dir-locals.el` file, or by calling `(dir-locals-set-directory-class)`:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables
- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

I prefer the directory class approach myself, and I was thinking that it's a shame that there isn't an analogous approach for file local variables, but I found that the directory class code actually works perfectly with files, and the only issue is that `dir-locals-set-directory-class` calls `file-name-as-directory` on its argument, which prevents it from being matched, due to the trailing slash.

The following therefore is a way to configure directory local variables for a single file, without modifying the file itself, or affecting other files under the same parent directory.

```
(defun my-file-locals-set-directory-class (file class &optional mtime)
  "Enable 'directory local' classes for individual files,
by allowing non-directories in `dir-locals-directory-cache'.
Adapted from `dir-locals-set-directory-class'."
  (setq file (expand-file-name file))
  (unless (assq class dir-locals-class-alist)
    (error "No such class `%s'" (symbol-name class)))
  (push (list file class mtime) dir-locals-directory-cache))

(dir-locals-set-class-variables
 'my-javascript-class
 '((nil . ((js-indent-level . 2)
           (indent-tabs-mode . nil)))))

(my-file-locals-set-directory-class
 "path/to/the/file.js" 'my-javascript-class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a snippet of code in my `init.el` that tries to auto-detect files that use 2-space indents, and switch Emacs's indentation for that file to 2 spaces when it sees such files:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (string-match-p "^  [A-Za-z]" (buffer-string))
              (make-variable-buffer-local 'js-indent-level)
              (set-variable 'js-indent-level 2))))
```

Comment: This auto-detection routine seems to be the most convenient for me.