# emacs indentation settings are messed up for a single file.

Tags: python, emacs, indentation

I have a single python file for all bunch of functions I've written to refer to. I use this file for sometime now, and for the past couple of days, when I add new stuff to the file, the indentation is wrong. Basically, it is 8 spaces instead of four. This is the only file that does that, and I have no idea why. I read that you can [set this manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240111/emacs-set-tab-indent-for-just-one-file-on-the-fly), but I didn't do that, so this is not the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See this related thread for examples on how to set tab-width distances, etc.:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1819405/2112489  That thread also contains examples of how to use those settings with a major-mode hook.  You'll need to check what major mode that particular file is in and if necessary add it to your auto-mode-alist -- e.g., `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.txt\\'" . lawlist-text-mode))`.

Comment: Try to set `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` to `nil`, and check whether that fixes this issue…

Comment: @lunaryorn Sadly, that didn't work.

Comment: @lawlist What I don't understand is why does this happen to a single file. And why did this happen to begin this if I didn't alter the files.